# Redirect page to div with Javascript using Jquery Mobile Multi-page template

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an android app, and I want to add a function to check if the user is connected to the internet. If they are not, I display an alert and then want to redirect them away from a 'page'. The problem is however that I am using a Jquery Mobile Multi-Page template. So technically I am not redirecting to a page, it is a div. My code is as the following:

```
networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
```

if (networkState == Connection.NONE)
{
  alert('No internet connection detected');
  window.location.href = "#seconddiv"
};

However this does not work, and if I set it as index.html it goes right back to the start of the app, which is not acceptable. Does anyone know how to just get it to redirect to a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `$.mobile.changePage` function: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#seconddiv"));
```